# How to skip previous layout in NextJS

Tags: next.js

I'm building app in NextJS and I have a root `/app/books/[name]` where in `layout.tsx` I've put book tree (sidebar). But I have also a route `/app/books/[name]/edit` where the layout should be actually skipped because similar tree (sidebar) is rendered in `/app/books/[name]/edit/page.tsx`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the latest version of NextJs, it gives the functionality to provide a different layout other than the parent one to use for one particular page by adding another layout file for the route.

But if you have a sidebar in your main layout and do not wish to use that for edit page, you can either change the routes as mentioned in the link below

[Routing in NextJs](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/47686)

or you can change the structure for parent and child as mentioned here.

[Nextjs  - Codeevolution](https://youtu.be/9g_3Zsoj17I?si=Bd8x0L5F2HYQzg0t)

[Nextjs official](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#per-page-layouts)

Comment: Do you have a link to nextjs docs for the first paragraph you wrote?

Comment: I have added the link in the answer. do check